# Configure SQL Server in memory (embedded) database for testing purpose in Spring

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

How do I configure my Spring Boot application so that when I run unit tests it will use embedded SQL Server so that stored procedures can be executed?

Answer (score 0):

use spring boot jpa

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

have a application-local.yaml config

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
```

MODE can be any depending upon your dev or prod db to simulate the same.

add the following in build.gradle

```
bootRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=local"]
}
```

Comment: can you give an example/code snippet for configurations and all the properties? During application load I got syntax error for procedure execution. Is MS sql procedure execution is compatible in the above mode?

Comment: Adding to above point, stored procedures are in ms sql compatible syntax.
Error is : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext 
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement [42001-148]